# How to configure proxyTable to reroute AJAX calls from Vue.js CLI to an exterior API?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Based on the documentation I can find, I have tried to connect to an API on localhost from inside my Vue.js app in the following ways, once using **vue-reponse** and once using **axios**. Each way returns an error that it can't find the resource.

What do I have to do to get the proxyTable to reroute correctly to my AJAX data source which is at `http://localhost/data.php`?

---

### index.js:

```
proxyTable: {
  api: {
    target: "http://localhost",
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" }
  }
}
```

---

### vue-response:

```
this.$http.post('api/data.php', data).then(response => {
    this.activity = response.data['activity'];
    console.log(this.activity);
}, response => {
    console.log('Error: ' + response.statusText);
});
```

> Error: Not Found

---

### axios:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'api/data.php',
    data: {
        smartTaskIdCode: 'pageActivityByMonth',
        yearMonth: '2017-09'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(that.activity);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

> Error: Request failed with status code 404

## Addendum

After researching this a bit more, I am quite sure that the following is the correct syntax:

### index.js

```
proxyTable: {
  "/api": {
    target: "http://localhost:80/api",
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" }
  }
},
```

### Test.vue

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/data.php',
    data: {
        smartTaskIdCode: 'pageActivityByMonth',
        yearMonth: '2017-09'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(that.activity);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

But I still get the following error:

> Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: You need a `/` before `api`. `'/api/data.php'`

Comment: I tried that as well, but I then get "Request failed with status code 404" as before.

Comment: I posted the detailed code in Addendum above of what I think is the correct syntax based on other examples I have found which apparently work. But the above still gives me the error  "Request failed with status code 404".

Comment: same here and still no solution found

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Should the target not be "http://localhost:80/" and then 'data,php' gets appended to it? So the the full proxy is "http://localhost:80/data.php" and not "http://localhost:80/api/data.php"